# jQuery-ui Spinner change to update total

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am trying to show update total price (qty*price) whenever i click up/down button on spinner.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="price"  required id="price" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" value="0" name="quantity" id="quantity" required  style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" required class="form-control" value="">
```

**JS**

```
$('#quantity').spinner({
        change : function(event, ui){
            var qty = ui.value;
            var price = parseFloat($('price').val());
            total = qty*price;
            $('#total').val(total);
        }
     });
```

Comment: you are missing `#` in `$('price')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you were missing `#` in `$('price')`

Second, you should use `this.value` and not `ui.value`. Because if you add `console.log(ui)` you will notice its empty. You can read it [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-change)

```js
$('#quantity').spinner({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    var qty = this.value;
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    var total = qty * price;
    $('#total').val(total);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="price" required id="price" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" value="0" name="quantity" id="quantity" required style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" required class="form-control" value="">
```

If you want it to update while you press the up or down, use `stop`

```js
$('#quantity').spinner({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var qty = this.value;
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    var total = qty * price;
    $('#total').val(total);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="price" required id="price" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" value="0" name="quantity" id="quantity" required style="width: 50px; height: 30px;">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" required class="form-control" value="">
```

Comment: Yes. It works. But the calculated price show only when I focus on the text field. Is there possible way to show calculated price automatically when i change the spinner?

Comment: @HeinHtetZor Your 5 sec to fast, look at my second snippet

Comment: @HeinHtetZor No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

As price is the `id` of the element you need to reference it using `#` in your jquery

```
var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
```